# Dashboard template Sonata Admin Bundle weird

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

My dashboard in Sonata Admin is completely weird.

I've removed the bundle from vendors and web.
Update with composer (all dev-versions of sonata) and clear the cache.

Still weird.

[erro http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/246/qgy8.png](http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/246/qgy8.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been an udpdate in the block_admin_list.html.twig in sonata admin bundle. See this [commit](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/commit/54d77ccf97ed0142b22c8ea512cbbacf7db2824f)

If you want to go back to the previous template, download this version of [block_admin_list.html.twig](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/4c3b7ffc20c8675b49938c5dba06d8acd92d1c3f/Resources/views/Block/block_admin_list.html.twig) and put this file in you app/Resources/view.

Now update your config.yml to change the list_block template :

```
sonata_admin:
    # your config
    # ...
    templates:
        list_block: ::block_admin_list.html.twig
```

I add the same bug yesterday and this workaround works fine.

Hope this helps

Comment: That's all you did? Cause now it's look like this: [link](http://oi39.tinypic.com/2iiwpib.jpg)